# Does exercise affect the number of muscle cells?

Tags: physiology, physical-fitness

Washington.edu reported [that](http://staff.washington.edu/griffin/musclephys.txt):

> Muscle cell number is affected by exercise level while young

and elitefitness.com [said](http://www.elitefitness.com/forum/womens-fitness-female-bodybuilding-training/can-muscle-cells-increase-number-223312.html):

> a trainee in the early stages of training would increase cell number

Where an unreferenced page on [wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle) said the opposite:

> Contrary to popular belief, the number of muscle fibres cannot be increased through exercise.

Which one is true, I'm a little bit confused?

*Note: I'm not asking about the increase in the cells' myofibril count, but the increase in the numbers of cells themselves.*

Comment: The question seems confusing to me. The wikipedia claim you find contradictory seems to be not about muscle cells, but about muscle fibries, i.e. myofibrils you are specifically writing you are not interested about. Can you clarify?

Comment: Was there any reason you chose to post this as a new question, rather than fix the [existing one](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/does-the-number-of-muscle-cells-increase-with-exercise)?

Comment: I lost my account cookie, so I'm leaving a response to Suma as a comment. You said: "be not about muscle cells, but about muscle fibries, i.e. myofibrils". As far as I can tell, muscle fibers is another word for muscle cells, and myofibrils are different.

Comment: And, to @Oddthinker, I asked a new question because despite there being a notable claim, the other question was closed based on its motivation (homework). I didn't know how to fix that, since it will have always been asked to solve a homework problem.

Answer (score 7):

It is evident that muscle growth happens through exercise. This article, *[Muscle growth and exercise](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2222798)* explains that there are three mechanisms involved:

> 1. by an increase in muscle cell numbers,
> 2. by an increase in muscle fiber diameter, and
> 3. by an increase in fiber length.

So, your question is whether the first mechanism is affected by exercise. The others are not related to the count of the cells, but how large each cell is.

The abstract goes on to explain:

> **Growth in cell numbers** is limited to the **prenatal** and **immediately postnatal period**, with the animals and man being born with or soon reaching their full complement of muscle cells.

So, the answer to the question is **no, exercise does not increase the number of muscle cells.**

---

Exercise does, however, increase muscle mass, by increasing the size and count of the components that make up each cell:

> Thus, **growth occurs** by either hypertrophy of the existing muscle fibers **by adding additional myofibrils to increase the muscle mass** or **by adding new sarcomeres to the ends of the existing muscle fibers to increase their length**. Both of these mechanisms occur during the growth process. **Growth in the girth of the muscle fibers appears to take place by splitting of the myofibrils**. This may be stimulated by development of stress creating an unequal pressure with splitting at the Z-band and development of additional SR and T-tubule systems. This adds to the diameter or girth of myofibers without any hyperplasia. The **growth in length occurs at either end of the fibers and results in addition of new sarcomeres**. In both cases, new myofibrillar protein must be synthesized and deposited in the muscle cells.

What determines adding sarcomeres and myofibrils?

You guessed right: [Exercise](http://www.austincc.edu/sziser/Biol%202404/2404LecNotes/2404LNExII/Muscle%20Physiology.pdf).

> Exercise stimulates the increase in myofibrils which increase the overall size of muscle cells.

Well exercised muscles can not only add more size but can also develop more **mitochondria**, **myoglobin**, **glycogen** and a **higher density of capillaries**.

Nutrition (especially protein intake) also plays an important role in muscle growth, but growth [cannot occur without](http://www.austincc.edu/sziser/Biol%202404/2404LecNotes/2404LNExII/Muscle%20Physiology.pdf) exercise.